# Can "Just so xxx" be taken as a set expression?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I heard couple of uses of *just so* in spoken English. For examples:

> Fine, but **just so** we're clear,
>
> **just so** you know,

My understanding is that it can be interpreted as *it's just like that, so* .... Is my interpretation correct? Is it sort of a set expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**just so** can mean "only because" or "only for the purpose of".

**just so we're clear, ...**

means

"I say what I am about to say only because I wish to avoid any misunderstanding."

If the phrase follows a statement, then it is "I said what I said only because I wish to avoid any misunderstanding."

**..., just so we're clear.**

The phrase is meant to draw the listener's attention. The effect is "I want you to pay attention to these words" or "I want you to pay attention to those words".

> OK. I can lend you my car, but just so we're clear, I meant what I said: you *must* return it no later than tomorrow at noon. Not 12:15. Not 12:30. I have to drive into the city for an important meeting, and noon is already cutting things close for me.

**just so you know, ...**
**..., just  so you know**

are similar. There it means

I am saying what I am about to say for the sole purpose of making you aware.

I said what I just said for the sole purpose of making you aware.

> OK. I can lend you my car.  But just so you know, it's almost out of gas, so be sure to get some before going anywhere.

Listen up: the car is almost out of gas.

P.S. The phrase **just so** in this sense of "only because" or "only for the purpose of" can be used to explain almost anything.

> "I'm engaged to be married", she said. "Just so you don't get the wrong idea".
>
> Just so you don't put the food in the oven without removing it first, the inner wrap is transparent.
>
> I'm putting a note on the fridge, just so you don't forget to water the plants while we're away.

As you can see with the "oven" and "transparent wrap" example, the phrase can be "meta" in its logic.   That sentence could be paraphrased "*I say the following* so you don't put it in the oven without removing the wrap first: *the wrap is transparent*".  The same is true with the "I'm engaged to be married" example, which means "*I said that* to make sure you don't get the wrong idea".

Comment: Any other similar expressions with this *just so* usage? Thanks!

Comment: There are millions.  Just so you don't get the wrong idea.   Just so you don't put it in the oven without removing the plastic wrap.  Just so you don't forget to water the plants.   **just so** means "only because" so it could partner with almost anything.  Just so you don't leave for Mars without your good luck charm, I put it in an envelope in your duffel bag.  When coupled with phrases like **we're clear** and **you know**, it refers to what is being said.

Comment: is it a common usage, since I didn't find it in dictionaries? Or is it regional?

Comment: There is no need for it to be in dictionaries as a special case because it is not one. **just** and **so** have their basic meanings here.

Comment: If that is the case, I assume that every native speaker should be able to understand it.

Comment: *Just so you don't get the wrong idea* sounds like *be careful you don't get the wrong idea*. Does it?

Comment: The speaker is saying "I am giving you that information to prevent you from getting the wrong idea."   Literally, to  **get an idea** means "to **receive** an idea".   In interpersonal exchanges the "signals" we receive (or think we are receiving) from the other person are how we "get ideas".

Comment: Is it a type of warning?

Answer (score -2):

No, your interpretation is incorrect in this context.

*just so* is a phrase used to *agree* or to say that everything is *fine and clear* or *arranged perfectly.*

> My mother wants everything has to be *just so* or else she gets angry!

Or...

> France should make to the finals ~ *Just so!*

Comment: I can get that meaning from dictionaries, but I feel your examples seem to be a little different from mine.